# SqlNullValueException Error

Tags: sql, asp.net

Hi I’m receiving an error on a webpage that I do some support for I didn't write/create the website, and am getting an error but just looking for a little more insight into where the error might be coming from, I know it’s an SQL error but is it coming from the website coed itself or from a database that is being accessed by the website?

**Error Message:**

Stack Trace:

> **[SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null Values.]**

Comment: The error is rather straightforward. Whatever method is being used is being passed a NULL and it expects data of some type. Can't really help much more without the source code or at least some information on the process throwing the error.

Comment: Ill give a rough guide of the logic we have userids that people login with and certain ids grant different things based on the first 3 digits but this is wont show the specific page even tho it has the correct rights off another system but this is the first id of its kind.